# How to remove a php hook from a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove some hooks so that product categories don't show up on the homepage (of a Wordpress Storefront child theme).

I have the following code in my functions.php, which isn't working:

```
/**
* REMOVE SECTIONS ON HOMEPAGE
*/

add_action( 'init', 'remove_storefront_on_sale_products', 10 );

function remove_storefront_on_sale_products () {
?>
remove_action( 'homepage', 'storefront_on_sale_products', 60 );
<?php
}
```

Comment: check on which action storefront_on_sale_products is attached ?

Comment: did you try to go to main page php and just remove the call for this functions from there .

Comment: Thanks, yes the page that calls the action is template-homepage.php. But it seems the code works now with php opening and closing tags in a different place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code aint working because your line `remove_action()` is located outside of the php-tags.

Remove `?>` and `<?php` in your above code and you should be fine.

Comment: How could something so simple, work??! I was following the same structure as all the other functions in my functions.php (I'm very new to this), which had the opening and closing php tags in those same places. Thank you :)

Comment: I see. Then you probably have HTML code in those other functions. :) Either you could step in and out of PHP with tags like above, or you could echo out HTML in PHP mode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all wordpress has not any action like "homepage" so you need to verify which action you are calling so if you want to remove function output only from homepage then you can do it by conditionally and secondly you didn't write proper php code, To achieve this you can write following in method.

```
if(!is_home()){
  //Do stuff here if it is not homepage
}


OR

if(get_the_ID()!=101){ //101 your page id in which you don't want to show this
  //Do stuff here if it is not homepage
}
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks Hiren, it seems I just needed to remove the opening and closing php tags and it worked, but thanks anyway.